# Data binding performance issues

Tags: wpf, data-binding, graphics, gis

I am writing a map control that can display a bench of geometries. For better performance, I draw all my geometries using `DrawingVisual`s which I then write into a `RenderTargetBitmap` as shown in the code below:

```
public class Map{
   public ImageSource MapDrawingImage{get;set;}

   private void RenderMap(){
    MapDrawingImage= new RenderTargetBitmap(w, h, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    foreach (Layer layer in map.Layers) {
        System.Windows.Media.DrawingVisual layerDrawing = Render(layer, map);
        MapDrawingImage.Render(layerDrawing);
    }
   }
}
```

In order to display the map, the main window has an `Image` control which `Source` is set to `Map.MapDrawingImage` image source. To automatically update the image, I use the following data binding:

```
    RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(mapImage, BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality);
    // Map image binding
    Binding mapBinding = new Binding();
    mapBinding.Source = map;
    mapBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("MapDrawingImage");
    mapImage.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, mapBinding);
```

This works very well when the map is static. However, in a dynamic mode where the map is updated at a rate of 5 to 10 times a second, the data binding seems to fall a bit short behind and the application slows down. I have searched for long days and I found out that:

1. `RenderTargetBitmap` does not use hardware acceleration thus causing some delays when rendering the map.
2. Data binding might also cause some delays refreshing the map image

Is there any better way to improve the map performance (`RenderTargetBitmap` replacement, data binding improvement) ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databinding is updated in a seperate thread. So this will always be with a delay. Also it works with a queue, so when the databinding can't keep up the queue will grow bigger and bigger. The solution would be that you use an image which is static and change the image itself instead of replacing it with another image.

Comment: A static image would be a shared resource that needs to be locked which still will bring the performance down

Comment: It doesn't have to be locked when the change is done in de Dispatcher thread.