# Invalidate own WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom WPF control that I made a couple of days ago:

```
 public class MapContext : FrameworkElement{
     //....
      protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc) {
         // Draw the map
         if (mapDrawing != null) dc.DrawDrawing(mapDrawing);
 }
```

The `mapDrawing` drawing is updated in another thread where all the geometries to display are computed, the thread then updates the UI by calling `InvalidateVisual()`:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(delegate { InvalidateVisual(); }));
```

On `InvalidateVisual`, [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.UIELEMENT.INVALIDATEVISUAL%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) says:

> Invalidates the rendering of the element, and forces a complete new layout pass. OnRender is called after the layout cycle is completed.

This is not the behaviour I want as the `MapContext` control layout did not change. Only the drawing inside has changed.

**Question**
Is there a proper way of forcing `OnRender` method to be called without doing a complete layout pass?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to force a re-render without a layout pass.
Since WPF uses a retained mode system, OnRender() does not work like the old WinAPI days. OnRender() simply stores a collection of drawing instructions, and WPF determines how and when to do the actual rendering.

If you need to change the look of your control independantly of sizing, I'd suggest you use something like a DrawingVisual, and using RenderOpen() to add your mapDrawing when you want it to change.

Comment: that was exactly my approach to the problem but at some point I need to throw those DrawingVisuals to the UI. Please see my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521789/data-binding-performance-issues

Comment: Not sure why you were converting to a bitmap? A DrawingVisual is the lowest level of a visible element. Everything visible derives from it, so to show one on screen, just set it to the Content property of a Window, Panel, or other ContentPresenter.

Comment: My map is not static, the drawings change something like 5 times per second so I thought it would be good to prepare a bitmap for display while processing the next view

Comment: I'm no expert but I would let WPF worry about that unless it becomes a performance problem. I'd just call RenderOpen() at 5Hz.

Comment: That is the problem. The application slows down a lot when drawing a big number of geometries

Comment: I don't understand. FrameworkElement.OnRender() is no different from DrawingVisual.BeginRender() from a drawing performance view.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of using your own control, you can draw image with your map and set this image as source to standard control? Such operations like drawing are usually taking some time so its better to prepare image in background and then switch it with currently displayed.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. This is what I initially did but the performance was very bad. Please see my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521789/data-binding-performance-issues