# Cannot find invalidate method for MainWindow

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to clear a drawing I created on the desktop. Heard that the best way is to use this.Invalidate().

The problem is when I add it to the code Visual Studio doesn't recognize the method. I'm using VS Express for Desktop 2012 and .NET 4.5.

Any ideas?

Error message:

> 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for
>   'Invalidate' and no extension method 'Invalidate' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Below is the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1, Enabled = true };
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);

    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            System.Drawing.Point pt = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;

            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, pt.X - 10, pt.Y - 10, 20, 20);                
        }

        this.Invalidate(); 
    }
}
```

Edit:

Everyone thanks for the heads up.

I've tried using RedrawWindow() but program keeps crashing everytime I start the test. Any ideas? I'm trying to update the desktop with this rectangle rc.

e.g.

RECT rc = new RECT( pt.X - 20, pt.Y - 20, pt.X + 20, pt.Y + 20 );

RedrawWindow(IntPtr.Zero, rc, IntPtr.Zero, 0x0400/*RDW_FRAME*/ | 0x0100/*RDW_UPDATENOW*/| 0x0001/*RDW_INVALIDATE*/);

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to invalidate the _desktop window_, using a native API call.

Comment: You're using `WPF`, not `Winforms`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalidate own WPF control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575203/invalidate-own-wpf-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're drawing on desktop Invalidating the mainwindow is not going to help. You need to Invalidate the `Desktop`.

To do that use [RedrawWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Here's the P/Invoke declaration of [RedrawWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.redrawwindow)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've tried using Pinvoke, but for some reason the RedrawWindow() doesn't seem to be redrawing anything.

Comment: I'll suggest you to create a new question with the code which doesn't work for you. Will try to help.

Comment: Thanks, create new question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684323/erasing-drawn-objects-on-desktop-using-c-sharp-wpf

Answer (score 1):

Is it not InvalidateVisual() in WPF?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `Invalidate()` method is a **Windows Forms** method, but you are using WPF.
In WPF, use [`InvalidateVisual()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx), the WPF equivalent of Windows Forms' `Invalidate()`

Comment: InvalidateVisual() is not the equivalent of Windows.Forms Invalidate(). It is *much* more expensive. The proper way to efficiently change a WPF drawing visual is to make a DrawingGroup, place it in the visual tree during OnRender() and then Open() it later and update the drawing commands in it. WPF will update the UI automatically.