# Erasing drawn objects on Desktop using Pinvoke on C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, leap-motion

I'm trying to create an interface program for the https://www.leapmotion.com device which requires the use of multiple desktop cursors. Since windows doesn't allow multiple cursors, my first task is to create a visual cursor that can be moved around the desktop and other windows.

The way I'm doing it now is to implement a loop and continuously draw the cursor object while clearing it. The drawing part works fine but I have problems doing the clearing part. I've tried using RedrawWindow() in Pinvoke but the code below just breaks during the testing.

Error msg:
     A call to PInvoke function 'WpfApplication1!WpfApplication1.MainWindow::RedrawWindow'
     has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not 
     match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters 
     of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Appreciate any advice that can be provided.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int RedrawWindow(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref RECT lprcUpdate, IntPtr hrgnUpdate, uint flags);

    ....

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {

            ///throw new NotImplementedException();
            System.Drawing.Point pt = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;



            System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(pt.X - 10, pt.Y - 10), new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20));


            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, rect);

            g.Dispose();

            RECT rc = new RECT( pt.X - 20, pt.Y - 20, pt.X + 20, pt.Y + 20 );

            RedrawWindow(IntPtr.Zero, ref rc, IntPtr.Zero, 0x0400/*RDW_FRAME*/ | 0x0100/*RDW_UPDATENOW*/| 0x0001/*RDW_INVALIDATE*/);

        }

    }
```

Edit:

I've amended the code above as per the suggestions from Alex Farber. (Thanks!)

I've also added the extra ref upon suggestion by Sriram Sakthivel. So now it can compile and run with no errors, however the ellipses drawn are still not being cleared by the RedrawWindow() command.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I see two problems in PInvoke declaration: BOOL in Win32 is 32-bit value, use int as return code, RECT must be passed by reference, and not by value.

Comment: Yes, expanding on what Alex said, I think the correct declaration is: [DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool RedrawWindow(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref RECT lprcUpdate, IntPtr hrgnUpdate, RedrawWindowFlags flags);   Source: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.redrawwindow

Comment: This has nothing to do with WPF.

Comment: Saying it's on WPF is just putting things into context. There are some methods that work on windows forms but not WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're missing ref in P/Invoke declaration

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool RedrawWindow(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref RECT lprcUpdate, IntPtr hrgnUpdate, uint flags);
```

and call it as

```
RedrawWindow(IntPtr.Zero, ref rc, IntPtr.Zero, ...);
                          ^ Note ref keyword here
```

Comment: Hi Siriam, I've also added the extra ref upon your suggestion. So now it can compile and run with no errors, however the ellipses drawn are still not being cleared by the RedrawWindow() command.

Any idea what is wrong?